# could not convert string to float: '05-01-17'

Tags: pandas, python-3.7

Dataset sample

```
   Product_Code    Warehouse   Product_Category   Date       Order_Demand

0  Product_0332    Whse_J     Category_021        05-01-17   1

1  Product_1909    Whse_J     Category_019        29-12-16   1
```

running the below code,

```
data = pd.concat([data['Date'].str.split().str[0].str.replace('_','').astype(float) for Date in data], axis=1)
```

can't convert string to float in date.

Comment: use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%d-%m-%y')`

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you please explain? Also provide expected output

Comment: I will predict Order_Demand by Date. But date is like string value. Now i have no idea in Date format convert to float or numeric value.

Comment: @Datanovice does not work well :(